# Dynamically Create JavaScript Object From MySQL Table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, object

Lets say I have this table `mytable`

`id | name | x | y`

I pull the the rows from `mytable` and create JavaScript objects with it like so:

**PHP**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo "new Object({$row["id"]}, '{$row["name"]}', {$row["desk_x"]}, {$row["desk_y"]});";
        echo '</script>';            
    }
}
```

**JS**

```
function Object(id, name, x, y) {
    var obj = {
        id:id, 
        name:name, 
        x:x, 
        y:y
    };
}
```

At the moment this is fine but lets say I want to add another column `color` to `mytable`

Basically I'm asking what do I write in PHP and JS to make this object dynamically, so you can have any columns and the `Object` object will just add a new property with the name of the column?

Comment: **Don't call your function `Object`!** `Object` already exists, and you will overwrite it, losing access to the original `Object`. And also, `Object` isn't really an expressive name for a constructor, is it?

Comment: I know. That was an example not my actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you're looking for is how to do this without AJAX (which you don't really need here).

Put the objects in an array, then output your JS variable:

PHP:

```
$rows = [];
if ($result->num_rows) 
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) $rows[] = $row; // append to array
echo "<script> var objArray = " . json_encode($rows) . "; </script>";
```

Comment: How would you do this using AJAX if it is better?

Comment: That sounds as if you have no idea what AJAX is/does. And you didn't say whether you tried my code. Or whether it works.

Comment: i tried your code and it works but if AJAX is the better option could you show me what you would write? I tried the AJAX code from @Ionut above but it didn't work well. I'm using AJAX to update data on my database already by the way.

Comment: I have no idea if AJAX is the better option or if you even need it. I'm sorry but it's kind of hard for me to estimate your level of knowledge, and I have no idea how much more info you need (and SO isn't a beginner's coding school). Asking me to transform my code to AJAX means you have no idea how to use it, and this question (or website) is not the place to learn how to use AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `AJAX` to send data from serverside to clientside. Lets say you have a `PHP` file called `script.php` with your code:

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'testing'){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
          echo json_encode($result);
    }
}
```

And lets say you have a `JS` file called `script.js`. Here you will do your `AJAX` call towards the `PHP` script file like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'script.php',
  data: { action: 'testing' },
  success: function(response){
     console.log(response); //here you will have access to the object returned from the PHP script
  }
})
```

Comment: Im looking for a way to get the columns from the table and make a java-script object with the same properties

Comment: The code from my answer should do just what you need.

Comment: The console is printing my entire index.php file

Comment: It depends on what is in that `PHP` file. It should be only the part of code I just added to my answer. Or you can check the `$_GET` request.

Comment: @AdamStück, please check the updated code from my answer.